# Is there a way in SSRS to highlight an interactively sorted column

Tags: sorting, ssrs-2012, interactive

I have a report with several interactive sort columns for sorting/ranking various metrics. I would like to highlight the column or even just the column header that is sorted. Is there a property that will tell me which column the report is sorted on?

I have not been able to find any threads that address this question.

Answer (score 0):

No - there are no properties in SSRS to let the code know that the column is being sorted.

If you wanted to put in the effort, you could add a parameter with column names for the sorting. Then just set the table or Groups SORTING by your parameter using a Switch statement and the background color of the header and/or data cell(s) using an IIF for each column for the color.

SORT EXPRESSION:

```
=SWITCH(Parameters!SORTING.Value = "NAME", Fields!NAME.Value, 
    Parameters!SORTING.Value = "AGE", Fields!AGE.Value)
```

Background Color Expression for a NAME column:

```
=IIF(Parameters!SORTING.Value = "NAME", "Whitesmoke", "White")
```

For the other columns, just use the column name.

To be a little slicker, you could use the ACTION on the column header for each field to set the parameter and recall the report rather than forcing the user to hit View Report. You would Specify the same report but Add the SORTING parameter and hard code the columns name (which has to be the same as the SWITCH function).

Unfortunately, this would require the report to rerun each time the user wanted to sort.

Kinda lame but it's the only way that I can think of to do it.